# Dry film PCB yellow light

Tags: led, pcb, light

I print out a negative on acetate paper, I stick it on a copper plate with dry film, and I press it with an iron. While doing these operations, we have to be in yellow light, what is the content of this yellow light?

Answer (score 3):

It varies by the photoresist, but generally you want to block almost 100% of the light below 500nm in wavelength.

For example, [here](https://www.lithoprotect.com/en/products/uv-filter-sleeve/176/lithoprotect-uv-filter-sleeve-t5) is a commercially available filter sleeve that fits overtop of a T5 or T8 fluorescent bulb to block short wavelength light.

[image]

Comment: https://www.microchemicals.com/technical_information/photoresists_storage_ageing_refilling_dilution.pdf Look at page 2 Mehmet.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: thank you so much